# Number of days stay in Schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen

My husband and I applied for Schengen visa for a Cosmos Tour to Europe from Oct 4 to 19, 2014. We are leaving Paris for London after breakfast on Oct 19, 2014.

On the application form, we indicated 15 days number of days stay but indicated the exact day of arrival and departure. The visa granted to us indicated 15 days stay, with validity date as Oct. 2 to 31, 2014.

Our travel agent now says we need a visa indicating 16 days stay. May we know if we to apply for for another visa?

Comment: Cancelling the visa then re-applying has far less chances of success than just altering the tour...

Comment: It's better alter your flights or arrive to paris airport at the night and get a breakfast after passing the border.

Answer (score 2):

October 4 to October 19 is indeed sixteen days as far as visa regulations are concerned. You have to count each calendar day during which you will be in the Schengen area, including the days at each end of your stay and not simply the length of time.

If you are not able to come on October 5 instead, the best would be to contact the consulate and ask them what to do. They can certainly amend the visa, especially if they made a mistake (which does not appear to be the case here however). Beside the cost, applying for a new visa without clearing that with them beforehand is likely to cause even more confusion.